# Shell Scripting substring replacement

Tags: shell

I am new to Shell Scripting and I am stuck doing a problem.
I have a file with strings like abc_some varied text.ext, and want to translate it to abcTRY. Now there are many string in file with underscore(_), but I just need to replace those with extension(.ext)and a underscore , and all these string have varied text written between underscore and extension.

`Input=  abc_some varied text.ext`

`Output= abcTRY`

I have written this:

```
grep -o "abc_.*.ext"| cut -d '_' -f1
```

Now don't how to replace the remaining part with TRY , and also want to know if abc is also different, what to do.

Hope the question is clear. Thanks.

Comment: "Hope this question is clear." Nope. It isn't. Try showing some inputs and your expected outputs. Having said that, the anser may be `sed` or `awk` depending on how  complex the problem is...

Comment: Hello, please show us part of input file, desire output and what have you tried so far.

Comment: I hope it is clear now.

Comment: can the string be like `abc_some_varied_text.ext.txt`. I mean multiple underscore are present in a string.

Comment: Yes, we need to cut if from first underscore, but there can be many in the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sed` (with extended regex **ERE**) to do this:

```
sed -r 's/(abc)_.*?\.ext/\1TRY/g' file
```

To change the file inplace:

```
sed -r --in-place 's/(abc)_.*?\.ext/\1TRY/g' file
```

Or with Basic regex (**BRE**):

```
sed 's/\(abc\)_.*\.ext/\1TRY/g' file
```

Comment: Thanks.It works, any idea if the abc is also not fixed?

Comment: @user3631660 You can use a variable (`$abc`) and use it like :  `sed -r "s/($abc)_.*?\.ext/\1TRY/g" file`. Note that I used double quotes here...
And if the solution works, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick mark left of the answer.